# Sequelize, can't run 2 create after each other

Tags: vue.js, sequelize.js

I would like to create 2 data in a table but i always get some `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error` or something else.

```
bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, async function(err, hash) {
    let luser = await users.create({ label: username })
    uid = luser.id
    await usersParams.create({ user_id: uid, parameter_name: "hashedPassword", parameter_value: password })
    await usersParams.create({ user_id: uid, parameter_name: "email", parameter_value: email })
  })
```

Comment: Show your model definitions and associations between them

Comment: But if I use just one line of code, it work. The error pops when I try to execute that 2 line of code, first one always succeed and the second fails.

Comment: I suppose that a usersParams model has wrong primary key definition. That's why I asked you to show model definitions.